# Forge Viewer: Unique IDs for clickable objects

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit, autodesk-viewer

I am experimenting with Revit and the Forge Viewer and I noticed that Forge already has unique IDs for every thing you can click on in the Revit model, so I used those instead of assembly id in Revit.

As an example the door of my building has id: "3003".

My question is, where is this data stored and how can I change "3003" into "Door 1" (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Viewer gives access to 3 types of IDs when dealing with Revit files:

1. **dbId**: this is Viewer specific and used to manipulate elements on Viewer, such as for `.getProperties()` method.
2. **Revit ElementID**: actually exposed as part of the **Name** property on Viewer. When you select something, on the Property panel, the title is in the form of "Name [12345]", so you can parse this name string and extract the name.
3. **Revit Unique ID**: exposed as **externalId** property on the `.getProperty()` response.

This [sample app](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/bim360appstore-model.derivative-nodejs-xls.exporter) exports properties into a spreadsheet, it may be relevant for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the summary. I successfully chaged the viewer to access the Revit ElementID and as as example on of the objects are showing: "5173305", not "Name [5173305]. I would really like it to retrieve the name of the family aswell. How is this accessible?

Comment: to get the family you need the parent hierarchy node for a given element (selected on screen) with `viewer.getObjectTree`, then use `.getNodeParentId`, see more at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45594631/4838205